# Using Google Cloud Armor to Block Requests to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Does Google Cloud Armor support blocking requests to public Google Cloud Storage buckets? I haven't been able to determine if GC Storage counts as a backend service.

The scenario is I would like to block various IP addresses from accessing a public GC Storage bucket. I would want to block Canadians, Azure, and IPs scanning for obviously wrong junk, like PHP files for example. The GC Storage access logs are getting dumped to a GC Storage bucket for analysis, and based on the analysis the scanning IPs are found.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google Cloud Storage counts as a backend service.

But, IP deny list/allow list for HTTP(S) Load Balancing is not supported for Cloud Storage backends. See [Security Policy Concepts - Restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-concepts#restrictions) for details.

Google Cloud Armor security policies are available only for backend services behind an external HTTP(S) load balancer. You can not use Google Cloud Armor for blocking requests to public Google Cloud Storage buckets